# Openxlsx problem in using header parameter

Tags: r, excel, header, openxlsx

I have used similar code before and had no problem.
b <- read.xlsx("sample.xlsx",startRow = 3,sheet = 1) works
b <- read.xlsx("sample.xlsx",startRow = 3,sheet = 1, header = TRUE) does not work (I am wanting to use header = FALSE but since that didn't work, I am trying with header = FALSE)
Needless to say,
b <- read.xlsx("sample.xlsx",startRow = 4,sheet = 1, header = FALSE) does not work either.

For my sample, the data is
a  b in row 3 and 2 rows of data

Comment: In `openxlsx`, the `read.xlsx` function has a `colNames` argument that can be TRUE or FALSE, but there's no `header` argument. For additional information, run`?read.xlsx` to see the help for the `read.xlsx` function. Is it possible you're confusing this with the `read.xlsx` function in the `xlsx` package, which *does* have a `header` argument.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using col_names with read_excel last night.  I didn't think about the  function being present in multiple packages with different options.